# Importing bone animations to android?

Tags: android, animation

Supose i ´ve got a walking character  animation, how do i import it from android.
I know that you can do sprite with xml files (although it isnt smooth), but imnot really sure how to do it with bone animations.

Or is there a way to make some basic character animation in android?

If it helps im using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a video in android. For example you can use powtoon and make custom animations and presentations as a video and use it in your android project.It will solve the purpose and will be easy for you.Hope this helps :)

EDIT:

Code for image animation in android

```
package com.abc.def;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Anim extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_anim);

  ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
  rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    rocketAnimation.start();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}



}
```

Comment: Does powtoon alows transparent background?

Comment: that is sprite animation!

Comment: @qerahile That is why i am thinking that if you could make a video of your animation that you require then it will be a lot easier to code and manage. What do you think? You may also make a video of sprite animation and when you use the video it will be a lot more smooth.

Comment: i ll give it a try, wait a few days :)

Comment: @qerahile Rearding transparency, yes!! you can achieve it using a surfaceview.Also read about alpha property..

Comment: Powtoon is not what i was looking for(besides that it has the logo). I im going to do an animation in unity and then sprite, seams the most simple.    I ll  leave it open in case other idea pops out, but thanks.

Comment: @qerahile Your idea seems reasonably good !!! I will let you know if I come up with something useful :).